# I want Activity to finish if i press ESCAPE button on an AlertDialog in an Activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have 3 Activities **A,B & C**.

I present some video links in Activity **A** in a list. If user clicks on an item, i load Activity **B** in which i do some verification of user's data such as ask him to provide his Login info in an **AlertDialog**. I present two buttons in this dialog to **Login** & **Cancel**. If user presses **Login** i verify his info and open Activity **C** where i play his selected video. But If user presses **Cancel**, i **finish()** Activity **B** to load Activity **A**.

This works fine if user only interacts through burrons.

But Issue arises that when i press **ESCAPE** button on my keyboard/D-Pad when the **AlertDialog** is open. The dialog disappears but the Activity **B** does not **finish()**. I have overridden **onKeyDown** of Activity **B** where i do the following.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown : calling finish() manually");
        finish();
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

But it does not work WHEN i press **ESCAPE** on an open **AlertDialog**.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: please confirm if onKeyDown has been invoked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the setOnKeyListener event of AlertDialog and do paste the following code in it. It will also close the activity on BACK button:

```
 @Override

    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE)                                 
        {           
            yourActivity.finish();
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
```